# Where does the word "scrub" come from as another word for "scroll"?

Tags: etymology

It seems like only within the last year I've noticed this usage, as a verb to view various parts of a digital resource. Dictionary.com does not have any definition for **scrub** that is similar to the verb form of **scroll** to view various parts of a digital resource.

Usage examples:

1. [A paraphrased tooltip on YouTube on mobile]
   Swipe upward for fine-scrubbing
2. [In technical documentation for a video sequencer editor]
   Scrub to the end of the sequence . . .

Comment: I assume @jamiie means the sense used in moving through a media file such as https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrubbing_(audio)

Comment: @Cascabel okay edited

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose yes, and so for I've seen it for media other than audio but your link seems to guide toward its more probable origination

Comment: Yeah, it was the first that came up. I looked around and couldn't find anything authoritative but one theory could be that it came into the media usage as a synonym for clean. As in "could you scrub this footage and take out unusable clips" (scrub being the word of choice because it implies a repeated process,  maybe going over a few times,  in a somewhat random pattern). It then just mean going through repeatedly and now it means nonlinear review. Just some guesses.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose I can't vote yet but thank you, I think you're right